# Passing parameters from Teamcity (properties) to the command line

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to pass a teamcity parameter (the project name) to a command line, but the command line does not pick it up. From teamcity's side, what is the way to do this?

I had done it before but something changed!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `%paramater_name%` into Custom script or Command parameters fields.

Comment: If you are passing parameters to a .cmd or .bat file you need to make Environment Parameters in Team City. System Parameters will not get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass parameter to the script you should define either
environment or system parameter in your build configuration. A name of the parameter should
start with `evn.` or `system.`. Parameters without
such prefixes are called configuration parameters and they are
not passed to the build. See [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Parameters) for details (I assume you are using TeamCity 6.5).